# Looking for tasks time line builder tool

Tags: time-management

I am looking for a tool that will help me to manage the time line of my team tasks in coming 3-6 months.

The requirements are:

1. group team members (ie backend,UI,QA,designers etc.)
2. assign to each task number of resources from each group
3. the tool should create o help to create time line from the tasks and the available resources.
4. This tool should identify when I am overbooking or under booking resources

This is how I manage it today in excel:
[image]

I tried Asana, Wrike ,teamweek and more but they are not fit the my needs.

Comment: Do you mean traditional [project management software](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management_software)? Specifically, a [Gantt Chart](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart). If not, how are your needs different?

Comment: AS mentioned above I tried several tools but they were over-killing and did not meet my needs,

Comment: Can you explain more about how they did not meet your needs? That would help us to recommend something.

Comment: 1. did not manage to group my team members into skills (back end,UI,QA,designers etc.).
2. I did nit mange to set task with resource. not the name of the team member but skill (2 dev, 1 qa ,0.5 designer etc)
3.tool should help me utilizes all team members and show me when I over booked them or under booked them.

Comment: I added an image from excel whcih show how I use it today with excel

Answer (score 2):

Tools to look at:

[Ace Project](http://www.aceproject.com/)  This is a paid, hosted service I have used. This tool allows you to add and control team members, assign them to groups, assign tasks and show a Gantt chart timeline.

[Podio](http://podio.com/)  This online workspace takes a social approach to project management and works with Google Apps. Groups and team members may be assigned to tasks.

[Trello](http://trello.com/) My favorite tool.  However, this tool does not display timelines.  "Boards" (projects) have team members added, assigned "cards" (tasks) and "lists" (project steps).  This tool is very visual and easy to navigate.

Each tool has a different approach to timeline building and task tracking.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, none of them fit to my needs.

Comment: Kevan, please do not simply list names; answers should show how your recommendations match the OP's requirements, and what makes them recommendable. For a guide, please see [our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Targetprocess supports:

1. [Teams](https://guide.targetprocess.com/teams-and-projects.html); "Any crazy mix of teams and projects is supported". You can create your own teams for your needs, eg backend, UI, QA, designers etc.
2. [Assign work to teams](https://guide.targetprocess.com/how-to-start/how-to-use-teams.html); Where work has an estimated effort.
3. [Visualizing](https://guide.targetprocess.com/boards/timelines.html) [timelines](http://www.targetprocess.com/product/#timelines); get a high-level
   overview of how your work progresses with time.
4. [Allocation timeline](https://guide.targetprocess.com/mashups/allocation-timeline.html); shows over/underbooking of resources with color codes: red means someone is overloaded, gray means the workload is fine, yellow - there's no workload at all.

Comment: I play with Targetprocess  for few hours:
1. This is more for agile workflow
2. Overkill to my needs
3. Not intuitive at all
4. Does not feel my needs

Comment: Regarding your 2nd & 4th point in your comment; can you add some more details of your needs in the question?

Comment: First, the tool should be easy to use. Second, I need something to help me identify when each feature can be start and end. Third, identify when I am overbooking or under booking (for example if I have X developers I cannot work on features allocating X+1 developers.